# MySQL query for taking data from two tables with inner join, aliases

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, alias

I've got two tables:

```
use exercise;

create table Companies 
(
    ID  int,
    Name    varchar(100),
    City    varchar(100),
    c_size varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

insert into Companies(ID, Name, city, company_size) 
values
(222, 'Karma LLC','CITY2', 'big'),
(223, 'Manny Ind.','CITY1', 'medium'),
(224, 'Random PLC','CITY1', 'medium'),
(225, 'Hijack LLC','CITY1', 'medium'),
(226, 'Travels LLC','CITY1', 'small'),
(227, 'Mirana Ind.','CITY2', 'small'),
(228, 'Polla Ind.','CITY3', 'small'),
(229, 'Americano LLC','CITY3', 'small'),
(230, 'Macaroni LLC','CITY4', 'small');

CREATE TABLE INVOICES
(
    ID INT auto_increment,
    `DATE` DATE,
    Company INT,
    Amount DECIMAL(7,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO INVOICES(`DATE`,Company,Amount)
VALUES
('2014-01-02', 222, 19500.00),
('2014-01-02', 222, 29205),
('2014-01-07', 222, 152.50),
('2014-01-07', 223, 6590),
('2014-01-07', 223, 4999),
('2014-01-09', 224, 720.60),
('2014-01-09', 225, 1100),
('2014-02-05', 226, 885),
('2014-02-05', 222, 9678.7);
```

My task is simple: write query, which return companies from which the city paid most of the invoices (by Amount value).
I FEEL that there is needed to use `JOIN` and maybe alias for tables or something like that, but I'm fresh in `MySQL` and a little confused with these aspect of language. Looking for good tutorial/exercises.

The query should then return something like:

```
|---sum(amount)_for_city_which_paid_most---|---name_of_the_city---|  
|------------------number------------------|---------city---------|
```

Sorry for ASCII, but I feel like this is clear and fast way to present what I mean.
I also would like to know query which lists city_name and amount that companies from this city paid (something like above, but all cities, not just one).
Sorry for poor english :(

Comment: Simple? Carry on then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, something like this?

```
SELECT *,SUM(i.Amount) AS total_amount
FROM Companies c
JOIN INVOICES i ON c.ID=i.Company
GROUP BY c.City
ORDER BY total_amount desc
LIMIT 1
```

Edit: The second one doesn't work, since you wanted to group by city, which only exists in the Company table.

If you're only after the company ID, you can save yourself a join:

```
SELECT i.Company,SUM(i.Amount) AS total_amount
FROM INVOICES i
GROUP BY i.Company
ORDER BY total_amount desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The first one is ok for me, thank you! I had to fix one though: I changed "group by c.ID" for "group by c.City", so after I removed "limit 1" I've got: CITY1---amount_CITY1; I also removed "*" since I don't need all informations. But still I don't get how it get sum only for particular City, not the whole table, can you explain me that?

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, I thought you wanted sums by company. I'll update it

Comment: @DontHurtMe The secret is the group by. Basically, aggregate functions like SUM are intrinsically linked to the group by clause. By telling it to group by city, and sum, it was implied that we wanted to sum all amounts for each city. That's just how aggregate functions work in SQL

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount), city
FROM INVOICES, Companies c
WHERE Company=c.ID
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY SUM(Amount) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

SQL Fiddle link: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d4ca/4/0

Comment: Yea, it works as above answer, thank you! But as I asked guy above, can you explain me how it works? I mean, I don't fully understand how you sum only for CITY1, then CITY2 etc. Result is good, but I would like to know how MySQL know that I want amount from each city, not all in one. Is that "GROUP BY city" or something else?